# Can't use curl to https

Tags: php, curl

I have tried and searched for all possible ways to resolve this but I can't find any. My code was working at first and it stopped working all of a sudden. I have no problem with curl http, my problem is with the https and I do have a valid certificate. Below is my code:

```
$surl ='https://perfectmoney.is/acct/confirm.asp?AccountID='
    . urlencode($AccountID)
    . '&PassPhrase=' . urlencode($PassPhrase)
    . '&Payer_Account=' . urlencode($Payer_Account)
    . '&Payee_Account=' . urlencode($Payee_Account)
    . '&Amount=' . urlencode($Amount)
    . '&Memo=' . urlencode($Memo)
    . '&PAYMENT_ID=' . urlencode($PAYMENT_ID) . '';

$curl = curl_init($surl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "certificate/GeoTrustGlobalCA.crt");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: And the error you get is? If you don't get one, try looking at `curl_getinfo`. I would take a guess and say remove your CAINFO and VERIFYHOST lines and set VERIFYPEER to false and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you, but I later found out that there is nothing wrong with it and it has now been resolved. I found out that my port 80 was blocked because of an application on my host, it works fine after unblocking it. Thank you